# batファイル実行時、if内でsetが効かない

Tags: batch-file

以下のようなコマンドを.batに記述し、win10にて実行しました。
「2」を選択した時、`myValue`が「after」にならない理由が分かりません。

お詳しい方、お知恵拝借できましたら大変幸いです。

```
@echo off
set myValue="before"

SET /P selected="select y,n,2："
if /i {%selected%}=={y} (goto yes)
if /i {%selected%}=={yes} (goto yes)
if /i {%selected%}=={2} (
  echo this is %myValue%
  set myValue="after"
  echo this is %myValue%
  pause
)
:yes
  echo end
pause
```

Comment: 該当の回答だけでなく、それに付随するティップスまで精細に記載していただき感謝致します！丁重なご回答誠にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

それは`遅延環境変数の展開`というもので、IFやFORの中での環境変数の変更には設定と工夫が必要になります。
コマンドプロンプトで`HELP SETLOCAL`と実行すると説明の一部が表示されます。

他にはこの辺の記事で使い方が解説されています。
[【BAT】IF文やFOR文の括弧内で変更した変数の値を取得する方法](https://qiita.com/yaju/items/79f4f39559b1e1a343da)

> - `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`と`endlocal`で囲む
> - 遅延評価したい環境変数は`%`ではなく`!`で囲む

[batファイル 遅延変数のサンプル(if文/for文の注意点)](https://itsakura.com/windows-batfile-delay)
[cmdのforやif内値代入！setできない原因は遅延環境変数！](https://jisakupc-technical.info/programing/491/)

---

一方注意する必要もあったりするので、こんな記事もあります。
[SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansionの罠とその回避方法](https://qiita.com/yz2cm/items/4983be006116c369d08b)
[bat を遅延環境変数を使わないように書き換える](https://blog.cles.jp/item/11244)

---

質問のように文字列を表示するくらいだと以下のように最初の方と最後に挿入してIFの中の`%`を`!`に変えれば良いでしょう。

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set myValue="before"

SET /P selected="select y,n,2："
if /i {%selected%}=={y} (goto yes)
if /i {%selected%}=={yes} (goto yes)
if /i {%selected%}=={2} (
  echo this is !myValue!
  set myValue="after"
  echo this is !myValue!
  pause
)
:yes
  echo end
pause
ENDLOCAL
```